# Counting number of subsets with restriction

Tags: combinatorics

Let $x\geq 66$ be an integer and consider set $S = \{1,2,3,4....,x\}$

(1) $k$ is an integer with $66\leq k\leq x$. How many $66$-element subsets of $S$ are there whose largest element is equal to $k$?

(2) Use the answer in first part to prove -

$$\sum {k-1\choose 65}={x\choose 66}$$

I think the answer of part 1 is $k$ chooses $66$ because that way $k$ will be in all subsets. Since $k \leq 66$, $k$ will be the largest in each subset. Is there anything wrong with my logic? For part 2, I'm not sure how to go about proving that equation. Can anyone guide me to the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: Please check if my edit has changed your question. I'm not exactly sure about part 2.

Comment: Yes, that's my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your answer to Part 1 is incorrect. Here's a hint.

To be concrete, let's take the example of $k = 100$.

If you want to choose a subset with $66$ elements whose largest element is $100$, what are you allowed to choose freely?

Comment: I'm allowed to choose 65 and the last position would be for k.

Comment: 65 elements of what set?

Comment: 65 elements that are less than k?I'm thinking about not considering k, instead just create 65-elements with those numbers less than k.

Comment: Yes. How many numbers are there less than $k$?

Comment: Ok I think I got it. It's (k-1) choose 65 because k is 100 and we don't need to consider k so that's k-1. right?

Comment: If $k = 100$, then the number will be $\binom{99}{65}$. In general, it's what you said.